# How would you use a large plane, and be able to cut sections out if you needed?

Tags: selection-tools

I may be mistaken, but I cant find anything on this, as I want to cut sections to create game levels that are continuous from a large plane.  It is being used as the environment, and I think 15km square will be too much to render when trees, buildings, and play is on it.  I want to keep the large plane, but set up so I can edit, and play on only sections of it, I think using the clipping will do it, but I am unsure of how to set it for just cutting sections at a time, while keeping the whole environment in tact.

Comment: Have you considered using multiple smaller planes for your environment?  Think of tiles.You can edit the master world, and then just select subsets of it to link to other scenes.  I often have dedicated scenes for editing specific elements of my animations without having to work around all the other elements.

Comment: I want in world coordinates that will match on each level and have interlevel properties as well, say what you have in inventory follows you around to each level till you use or remove it.

Comment: What I suggested will satisfy your requirements.

Comment: I can accept that, if there is a tutorial or something that explains how.

Comment: http://www.pasteall.org/blend/35388 is a very quick example of a larger terrain made up of individual tiles.  I used an identical mesh because I was too lazy to customize each one, but you'd use one mesh for the side of a mountain and another mesh for the top of a mountain, and a different mesh for the top of a different mountain.